# Getting "global name 'FbxManager' is not defined"

Tags: python, webgl, global, batch-processing, fbx

I am working on creating a WebGL interface for which I am trying to convert FBX models to JSON file format in an automated process using python file, [convert_fbx_three.py](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/fbx/convert_to_threejs.py) (from [Mr. Doob's GitHub project](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/converters/fbx)) from command line.

When I try the following command to convert the FBX:

```
python convert_fbx_three.py Dolpine.fbx Dolpine
```

I get following errors:

Error in cmd:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "convert_fbx_three.py", line 1625, in <module>
 sdkManager, scene = InitializeSdkObjects()
 File "D:\xampp\htdocs\upload\user\fbx\FbxCommon.py", line 7, in InitializeSdkObjects
 lSdkManager = KFbxSdkManager.Create()
 NameError: global name 'FbxManager' is not defined
```

I am using Autodesk FBX SDK 2012.2 available [here](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=20425230) on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following:

```
import FbxCommon
.
.
.
lSdkManager, lScene = FbxCommon.InitializeSdkObjects()
```

Comment: this is not work, inside `InitializeSdkObjects` will call `FbxManager.Create()`, but op can not found FbxManager.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add environment variables pointing to the folder that contains `fbx.pyd`, `FbxCommon.py`, and `fbxsip.pyd` prior to calling anything in those modules.